# React useRef not updating consistently for conditionally rendered elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Across my app, there are some UX logic that needs to be shared. They are triggered by events, so I wrote 2 custom hooks. Let's call one `useRefWithCalc`. The other hook is a more standard `useEventListener`, similar to [this one](https://usehooks-ts.com/react-hook/use-event-listener).

`useRefWithCalc` calls the native `useRef`, has some internal handlers for UX, then calls `useEventListener` to attach those handlers. `useRefWithCalc` returns the `ref` created within, so another component can use this hook, and get the returned ref to attach to elements.

This has worked for me when the ref isn't attached to conditionally rendered elements.

The component looks something like this. Please take note on the 2 test logs.

```
const useEventListener = (event, listener, ref) => {\
    ...
    useEffect(() => {
        ...
        console.log("1. ref is: ", ref.current); // test logging 1.
        ref.current.addEventListener(event, listener);
        return () => {
            ref.current.removeEventListener(event, listener);
        }
    }, [event, listener, ref]);
}

const useRefWithCalc = (value) => {
    const ref = useRef(null);
    ...
    const calc = () => {
        // some calculations
    }
    ...
    useEventListener(event, calc, ref)
    return [ref, result]
}

// works perfectly
const WorkingElement = (props) => {
    const [ref, result] = useRefWithCalc(props.value);
    ...
    return <B ref={ref} />
}

// doesn't work consistently
const ConditionalElement = (props) => {
    const [state, setState] = useState(false);
    const [ref, result] = useRefWithCalc(props.value)

    useEffect(()=>{
        if (ref && ref.current) {
            ref.current.focus();
            console.log("2. ref is: ", ref.current); // test logging 2
        }
    }, [ref])
    ...
    return state ? <A> : <B ref={ref} />
}
```

The `<WorkingElement />` works just as expected. The ref gets attached, and handles events with no problem.

However, in the `<ConditionalElement />`, when B is mounted, **sometimes times test logging 1 won't fire. Test logging 2 always fires, and the ref gets the focus correctly. But this update is not passed into `useEventListener`**

Once `<B />` gets **1** subsequent update (e.g. when user inputs something), both logs will fire correctly, and the event listner gets attached correctly, and it work just as `<WorkingElement />`

---

Sorry for not posting the exact code. I feel like my approach is convoluted and might be wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In React when a ref changes, it doesn't trigger a component update, and `useEffect`s are not triggered.

I suggest to put your ref inside a state so that effects are triggered when the ref changes :

```
const [ref, setRef] = useState(undefined)

return (
  <B ref={setRef}/>
)
```

Comment: Is this documented anywhere? It's also important to note that you are using `setRef` as the value here, because React will call it as a callback. It will not use `ref.current` though, it will just call the setter and update the `ref` state variable.

Comment: yep, no `ref.current`. Regarding documentation, I don't know if it's documented anywhere, but it's a common pattern, see for example the [react-popper documentation here](https://popper.js.org/react-popper/v2/#example).